# c# default value for Convert.ToBoolean

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
bool SilentUpdate { get; set;}
....
   string temp = "";
   SilentUpdate = Convert.ToBoolean(temp ?? "false");
```

I want to default SilentUpdate to false when temp string is empty. The above code still issue error "String was not recognized as a valid Boolean."

How can I do that?

Comment: `string.IsNullOrEmpty(temp) ? "false" : temp`?

Comment: It's not JavaScript :).  You can't do "truthy" evaluations based on string length.  You have to be explicit in your check, as in @Rhumborl's suggestion.

Comment: As @Rhumborl suggests. Also note that "" is not null as recognized by ?? coalescing operator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is slightly diffrent logic, but this will give you `false` for any value that does not correctly convert in to a Boolean which is likely what you are really looking for.

```
string temp = "";
bool result
if(!bool.TryParse(temp, out result))
{
    result = false; //This line and the `if` is not actually necessary, 
                    //result will be false if the parse fails.
}

SilentUpdate = result;
```

Comment: The default value of a bool is false, so setting result to false explicitly in the if statement is not entirely necessary :-)

Comment: @ThomasMulder Yes, I said that exact thing I said in the two lines of comments in the code.

Answer (score 5):

Using [`Convert.ToBoolean`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86hw82a3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the string being parsed must either be a [`Boolean.TrueString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.truestring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [`Boolean.FalseString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.falsestring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or `null`. If it's any other value, then an exception will be thrown, so you must ensure to add a `try...catch` around the conversion code, example:

```
string temp = "nope";
SilentUpdate = Convert.ToBoolean(temp); // Exception: "String is not recognized as a valid Boolean"
```

Using [`Boolean.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you can alleviate this, as well as get a default value as you're wanting:

```
string temp = "";
bool res = false;
SilentUpdate = (Boolean.TryParse(temp, out res) ? res : false);
```

`Boolean.TryParse` returns `true` or `false` if the parse succeeded and if it succeeded the ternary logic returns what was parsed, otherwise it's false.

Hope that can help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Boolean.TryParse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) method as well. It returns `bool` based on whether the parsing has succeeded or not.

```
     bool flag;
     if (Boolean.TryParse(temp, out flag))
```

Comment: if you just change it to `bool flag = false;` then you don't need to worry about the if statement. It's default to false if it's not parsable.

Answer (score 1):

The code should be:

```
SilentUpdate = Convert.ToBoolean(string.IsNullOrEmpty(temp) ? "false" : temp)
```

You're misusing the [`??` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) in your code. It only returns the second operand if the first one is `null`, not falsy. Empty string is not `null` and therefore `temp ?? "false"` returns the empty string, which is not a valid boolean value.